# ifup eth0 on every boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.04

04 and the network card is not supported by default kernel.
So, I upgrade kernel to 3.2 and it support it.
However, every time I reboot machine, need to `sudo ifup eth0` to bring up it.

How can I modify some config to auto bring up eht0?
(not write in `/etc/rc.local`, cause I mount NFS on `/etc/fstab`, it need to mount first than `rc.local`).

Comment: can you pleas run "> cat /etc/network/interfaces" and post here.

Comment: oops, maybe i forgot auto eth0, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Ubuntu you have to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and set default configuration data for every network interface on your system.

Put both `auto` and your interface name on a separate line before your interface configuration in order to bring it up at startup.

Example:
When your configuration is like this

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

You have to change it to this

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

[Network card configuration](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/)

Comment: Just to next users: not simply "Put `auto` before", in fact is a line before your `iface` definition: `auto <interface_name>`. Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/

Answer (score 12):

you can eidt **`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`** file.
serach `ONBOOT` with file content.
and change `ONBOOT=no` to `ONBOOT=yes`.

Comment: be careful, the question is tagged Ubuntu-11.04. Your method is for Red Hat-like distros

Comment: Thanks, it worked on Centos 7